How to find memory leak in authenticated end points for Ruby on Rails application?
I am working on finding memory leaks in my ruby on Rails application. I found one of rails supported plugin called as derailed_benchmarks
It's providing a below command to test end points in order to get details about memory and objects allocation used by that end point. It's work good when home page URL.
The command is

$ bundle exec derailed exec perf:objects

But I am unable to check end points which enabled with devise authentication.
Internally this plugin using curl command to test the end points.
But am unable to test the end point which restricted with devise authentication.
Anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

https://github.com/zombocom/derailed_benchmarks?tab=readme-ov-file#authentication

@dbugger I tried this configuration already, but authentication got failure and redirected home page.

If you are sure you set up the configuration correctly, Perhaps open an issue on the derailed gem repo.
